# Disabling address bar in the Windows open/save file dialog

Tags: windows

Is it possible to somehow disable the navigation bar in the default open and save dialogs from Windows?

[image]

We use a VM to stream a desktop application and we block almost everything using AppLocker. As you can see in the picture, the users cannot see the C: drive, but if they type any path in the address bar, they can navigate to anywhere in the file system.

I don't know, maybe some Windows settings or registry entries. By the way, we are using Windows Server 2019.

Comment: It's not possible to change which File Dialog is used by an application unless you have the source code.  Even if you do have the source code, then the legacy file dialog that would meet your goals, no longer can be used on modern versions of Windows.

Comment: Thanks for that information.

Comment: Note that each *application* can choose to customize the Open/Save dialog, e.g., in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193944/how-to-customize-open-save-file-dialogs . If you use only custom apps, then the software engineer can design it accordingly.

Comment: Also note that you can also type C:\ or any other path in the filename bar and press enter and it will also work. You can even type `*.*` there to show all files, which will override the `*.xlsx` filter.

Comment: LPChip and DrMoishe are correct. I think this is, right now, and XY problem: You've made some assumptions about what the solution to a problem will be, and these assumptions, while not bad, aren't correct given your situation. You should take a step backwards and look at the original problem and find a better way to solve this problem. Just trying to "block almost everything" isn't very clear. What is "almost", for instance. You need to be able to define what should be blocked, or you should be able to define what should be NOT blocked, and then block everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the answers given in the comments:

1. Applications get to decide WHICH dialog is used to navigate/locate files on the system. There is not an OS-wide way to capture all possible Open/Save dialogs and redirect them to something else.
2. Even within more limited Open/Save dialogs, or if you were able to, theoretically, disable that top bar, typing a drive or folder path into the File Name field at the bottom of the dialog you show will take you to that path, so simply removing that top bar will not prevent the access you're trying to prevent.

For a limited access system you will need to find some other way to do what you're trying to do. App virtualization systems usually have controls that allow you to limit accesses, or to set the accesses to the users' system rather than the host system (Citrix and access to local resources, for instance).

As it is currently written, your question does not specify a clear list of the things you're actually trying to prevent/lock down. This post can only answer the questions you HAVE asked, and this answer is: you can't.